# Evaluating double integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the double integral  $$I=\iint_D y dy dx$$ where $D$ is area bounded by

$$D= \{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1, x^2+y^2\leq2x, y\leq0 \}$$

First off, function I am evaluating is $z=y$ and it's just one plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, this is the $D$ I am looking for:
[image]

Now, I should integrate over the intersection of these two circles where $y<0$. Obviously, I should use polar coordinates so $$x=r\cos(\theta)\\ y=r\sin(\theta)$$, Jacobian is $r$ so it remains now to find the bounds of integration, however I am not quite sure how to do that, since the intersection point of two circles is $$(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)$$ I suppose that angle should go from $-\frac{\pi}{6}$ to $0$ but then, I could write out the equations of circles to get bounds for $r$, where $r$ should go from the blue circle to red circle, which means $$r \in [2\cos\theta, 1]$$ , but I am not quite sure is that correct way to do it because when i calculate it this way I get the positive result $$I=\frac{5}{12}$$, which is not what I expected since I am integrating over an area where $x$ is positive and $y$ is negative which means that I am actually finding a volume of body that's either in fourth or eighth octant, but, when I take a look at the function I am integrating I see that $z=y$ meaning that sign of $y$ will determine the sign of $z$ so I am finding a volume of a body that's located in eighth octant, so I expected a negative value here. Obviously, something is wrong, it might be $D$ or bounds of integration or calculations or ,the worst case probably, my reasoning. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: symmetry with respect to what? I am actually integrating the part where $y\leq 0$, not the whole intersection, just like i stated above.

Comment: Right, i didn't notice. Discarding my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to start with polar coordinates.

Your integral can be written (using the geometry of the domain), as 
$$I=\int_{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{0} \int_{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{  \sqrt{1-y^2}} y dx dy = \int_{\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{0} y \left(2 \sqrt{1-y^2}-1 \right) dy$$

Edit following OP's comment pointing out that the domain contains only region below x-axis:

Making the substitution $y=\sin\theta$,

$$I=\int_{\frac{-\pi}{3}}^0 \sin\theta (2\cos \theta-1) \cos\theta d\theta = -\frac{5}{24}$$

Comment: i don't understand how you got your upper bound for variable $y$. I explicitly stated that i am looking for the area $y\leq 0$ right bellow the picture, and if you check out $D$ again, you'll see that i did the same thing in the definition of $D$. Shouldn't then upper bound be zero actually?

Comment: @Mathemagical are you sure about the integration limits? $1-\sqrt[1-y ^2]$ is the arc of the circle centered in the origin translated up by 1. $\sqrt[1-y ^2]$ is the arc of the circle centered in the origin in the first quadrant.

Comment: @cdummie: I think you simply did a small mistake. The results is negative and you forget to divide by 2 i.e. I = -5/24

Comment: @cdummie ah.  I missed that. Sorry. In that case, the answer, I got on the lower half was -5/24 and on the upper 5/24. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: @cdummie: the result I got is the same of Yves Daoust.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the section of the area at ordinate $y$ is $\sqrt{1-y^2}-(1-\sqrt{1-y^2})$, and it cancels at $y=-\sqrt3/2$.

Then

$$I=\int_{y=-\sqrt3/2}^0 y\,\left(2\sqrt{1-y^2}-1\right)\,dy=\left.-\frac23(1-y^2)^{3/2}-\frac{y^2}2\right|_{y=-\sqrt3/2}^0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution I propose is based on the Green's theorem. Let R the interior of the region delimited by D, and let (P(x,y),Q(x,y)) a differentiable vector field. Then
\begin{equation}
\int_C P dx + Q dy = \int \int_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}) dx dy
\end{equation}
Now if we assume $P = -y^2/2$ and $Q = 0$ we have
\begin{equation}
-\int_C \frac{y^2}{2} dx = \int \int_R y dx dy
\end{equation}
We can then evaluate the integral over C. To do so we use the polar coordinated. We have two circles, but the only difference is that one is translated along the x-axis with respect to the other. If we consider the circle centered into the origin we have:
\begin{equation}
x(\theta)= \cos(\theta)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y(\theta)= \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
dx= -\sin(\theta) d\theta
\end{equation}
Then

\begin{equation}
-\int_{C_1} \frac{y^2}{2} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \sin^{3}(\theta)
\end{equation}
where $C_1$ is the circle centered into the origin.
For the second circle $dx$ is the same so you can find exactly the same expression. Once integrating with with the correct integration limits you get the value -5/24.